# Error en sort and map in React typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I made a constant that has two arrays. Using the index of the constant, I map the arrays to render them on the screen depending on the numerical value of a state (which is the same as the index of the array) to render the data I want at the moment:

index 0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUZhc.png)

index 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYuYl.png)

My problem is as follows: When I click on an element of index 1, the page breaks and takes element[indexOfFrag] (the mapped array with the state that has the index) as if it were undefined, which does not happen with index 0 and it works correctly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMu25.png)

More context:
I have a function called HandleDeleteElement so that when an element is clicked it is removed from the rendered list.

```
const handleDeleteElement = ( array: { fid: number; frag: string }[], id: number ) => {
    const newArray = array.filter((element) => element.fid !== id);
    setElements([newArray]);
};
```

And the code that according to Next gives me problems is this (as I said before, it says that it cannot sort an undefined element DX):

```
{showDiv && elements[indexOfFrag].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).map((frag, i) => (
    <div className={styles.frags} key={i} onClick={() => handleDeleteElement(elements[indexOfFrag], frag.fid)}>
     <h1>{frag.frag}</h1>
    </div>
))}
```

showDiv is a boolean state that, when true, renders the mapping. I did this because when the page was rendered, Next.js said that the server-side elements didn't match the client-side ones (I assumed it was the sort that was causing the problem, so I delayed it).

I tried using ChatGpt, but the recommendations it gave me still produce the same error: when I execute the handleDeleteElement function on an element with index 1, it becomes undefined and therefore the sort function can't be executed.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const sortedElements = elements[indexOfFrag].slice().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
     setElements(prevState => {
     const newState = [...prevState];
     newState[indexOfFrag] = sortedElements;
     return newState;});
    setShowDiv(true)
  }, []);
```

Comment: Must be in English.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: We need more code to discover issues rather than textual descriptions. Adding an `showDiv && elements[indexOfFrag] &&  elements[indexOfFrag].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)` **elements[indexOfFrag]&&** check may prevent errors, but it is not a fundamental solution to the problem.